# How can I make a gas-free network?

Tags: go-ethereum

I was developing on a network without gas until a while ago.
But the network became so slow that it created a new network.
But this network requires gas. How can I zero gas?

Comment: Which network you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to create a blockchain, you don't need gas fees. It is just a method to incentivize the node providers.

If running a chain node won't pay you, would you waste time and resources? And the second reason is to prevent the attackers from sending infinite transactions to crash the network.

And yes. You can make blockchain without gas fees. For example, HLF, Corda, and Quorum(although it is technically DLT). A lot of private companies use them to create their own private blockchains. And because it is private, they run their own nodes so they don't need need to pay anyone.

And if someone says there is legit gas-free nework, it is probably a scam. Be careful.

Tell me if it helps!